# apt-get update does not get the last version of pycharm ppa

Tags: apt, ppa, pycharm

I use [ppa:mystic-mirage/pycharm](https://launchpad.net/~viktor-krivak/+archive/ubuntu/pycharm) to getting pycharm community updates.

Despite the last version for my achitecture (Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS, xenial) is `2019.1-1~xenial` for more than one month, `sudo apt-get update` still shows the last available version as `2018.3.5-1~xenial`.

```
....:~$ sudo apt-get update                                
Atteint :57 http://ppa.launchpad.net/viktor-krivak/pycharm/ubuntu xenial InRelease
```

After  `apt-get update`:

```
....:~$ apt-cache policy pycharm
pycharm:

  Installé : 2018.3.5-1~xenial
  Candidat : 2018.3.5-1~xenial
 Table de version :
 *** 2018.3.5-1~xenial 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/viktor-krivak/pycharm/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I can't figure out why, and how to debug that...

Comment: Maybe a dumb question but... Have you ever done `sudo apt upgrade` meanwhile?

Comment: yep, and a number of time!

Comment: And no errors were reported?

Comment: I'm wondering what you see if you `apt-cache policy pycharm`  (i'm not sure how `apt-get update` alone tells you what you see)

Comment: no errors reported. Thanks for helping!

Comment: As a side note, JetBrains supports only three installation ways on Linux officially: via `snap` packages https://snapcraft.io/, with manual downloading `tar.gz` archive from the [official website](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=linux) or with [Toolbox App](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox/app/). [ppa:mystic-mirage/pycharm](https://launchpad.net/~viktor-krivak/+archive/ubuntu/pycharm) is supported by someone from the community.